# I am making a Christmas Lantern with Zelle graphics.py and I want the medium circles to blink random colored lights

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

This is my code. I wanted create a Christmas Lantern with lights. The lights are the medium circles which I commented. I can't seem to figure out how to create blinking random color lights in order to look like Christmas Lights.

Code:

```
from graphics import *
import random, time

def lantern():
    win = GraphWin('Lantern', 800, 800)

    #3 Large Circles
    c = [[400,300], [400,300], [400,300]]

    largeCircle = [250, 180, 100]

    for i in range (len(largeCircle)):
        c[i] = Circle(Point(c[i][0] ,c[i][1]), largeCircle[i])

    #10 Medium Circles
    mc = [[465,95], [560,155], [610,250], [610,360], [550,455], [245,447], [193,350], [193,250], [245,150], [350,92]]


    for i in range (len(mc)):
        mc[i] = Circle(Point(mc[i][0], mc[i][1]), 25)

    #11 Small Circles
    sc = [[450,160], [520,200], [550,265], [545,344], [508,410], [400,450], [290,405], [250,339], [250,265], [285,195], [355,155]]

    for i in range (len(sc)):
        sc[i] = Circle(Point(sc[i][0], sc[i][1]), 15)

    #5 XtraSmall Circles
    xsc = [[453,237], [474,325], [400,365], [325,325], [350,237]]

    for i in range (len(xsc)):
        xsc[i] = Circle(Point(xsc[i][0], xsc[i][1]), 8)

    #16 Lines
    l1 = [[532,90], [540,93], [620,180], [622,185], [613,430], [609,435], [520,520], [515,520], [310,457], [305,454], [240,380], [235,378], [178,187], [180,182], [265,90], [270,88]]
    l2 = [[500,150], [505,156], [555,210], [558,215], [555,390], [550,396], [490,454], [485,456], [275,519], [270,516], [180,420], [178,415], [242,216], [244,212], [300,150], [304,150]]
    n = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    for i in range (len(n)):
        n[i] = Line(Point(l1[i][0], l1[i][1]), Point(l2[i][0],l2[i][1]))


    #Star
    p1 = Polygon(Point(400,200), Point(440,260), Point(498,280), Point(450,320), Point(470,370), Point(400,345), Point(327,369), Point(345,320), Point(303,280), Point(360,260))

    #Red Box
    p2 = Polygon(Point(400,480), Point(480,560), Point(400,650), Point(325,560))

    #Triangle
    p3 = Polygon(Point(400,120), Point(437,207), Point(503,153), Point(478,238), Point(556,213), Point(500,280), Point(580,305), Point(495,330), Point(555,395), Point(470,373), Point(488,455), Point(400,400), Point(307,454), Point(328,370), Point(235,378), Point(305,330), Point(220,303), Point(303,280), Point(242,215),Point(330,230), Point(300,150), Point(370,205)) 

    r1 = Rectangle(Point(650,300),Point(580,305))
    r2 = Rectangle(Point(397,50),Point(404,120))
    r3 = Rectangle(Point(220,300),Point(150,305))


    for i in range(3):
        c[i].draw(win)
        c[i].setWidth(3)

    c[0].setFill('lavender')
    c[1].setFill('orange')
    c[2].setFill('red')

    for i in range(10):
        r = random.randrange(256)
        b = random.randrange(256)
        g = random.randrange(256)
        colors = color_rgb(r, g, b)
        mc[i].draw(win)
        mc[i].setWidth(3)
        mc[i].setFill(colors)

    for i in range(11):
        sc[i].draw(win)
        sc[i].setWidth(3)

    for i in range(5):
        xsc[i].draw(win)
        xsc[i].setWidth(3)

    for i in range(16):
        n[i].draw(win)
        n[i].setFill('brown')
        n[i].setWidth(3)


    p1.draw(win)
    p1.setWidth(3)
    p1.setFill('yellow')

    p2.draw(win)
    p2.setFill("red")
    p2.setWidth(3)

    p3.draw(win)
    p3.setWidth(3)
    p3.setOutline('purple')

    r1.draw(win)
    r1.setOutline('brown')
    r1.setWidth(3)

    r2.draw(win)
    r2.setOutline('brown')
    r2.setWidth(3)

    r3.draw(win)
    r3.setOutline('brown')
    r3.setWidth(3)

    message = Text(Point(400,560), '福')
    message.setSize(30)
    message.setFill('gold')
    message.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

lantern()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it. It's partially based on the information in the [Controlling Display Updates (Advanced)](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node15.html) section of the Zelle `graphics` module's online [documentation](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/index.html).

The modifications made to your code are indicated with `# ALL CAPS` comments. The construction of the `GraphWin` and its closing have been moved out of the `lantern()` function and and a loop has been added to periodically update the circles representing the lights.

Since redrawing the lights will be done many times, a function named `draw_mcs()` has been added and it is called repeatedly in a loop to generate successive "frames" of an animation to make the lights appear to make them appear to blink by occasionally drawing them in black. You can control the speed via the integer argument passed to the `update()` function at the end of the loop which is the number of times per second to redraw them.

In order to share data between `lantern()` and `draw_mcs()` functions, a couple of lists have been declared `global`. One of them is new and stores the color of each light so it will blink back on the same color it started with.

```
from graphics_5p0 import *
import random, time

BLACK = color_rgb(0,0,0)
RATE = 5


def lantern(win):
    global colors  # ADDED
    global mc      # ADDED

#    win = GraphWin('Lantern', 800, 800)  # MOVED.

    #3 Large Circles
    c = [[400,300], [400,300], [400,300]]

    largeCircle = [250, 180, 100]

    for i in range (len(largeCircle)):
        c[i] = Circle(Point(c[i][0] ,c[i][1]), largeCircle[i])

    #10 Medium Circles
    mc = [[465,95], [560,155], [610,250], [610,360], [550,455], [245,447], [193,350], [193,250], [245,150], [350,92]]


    for i in range (len(mc)):
        mc[i] = Circle(Point(mc[i][0], mc[i][1]), 25)

    #11 Small Circles
    sc = [[450,160], [520,200], [550,265], [545,344], [508,410], [400,450], [290,405], [250,339], [250,265], [285,195], [355,155]]

    for i in range (len(sc)):
        sc[i] = Circle(Point(sc[i][0], sc[i][1]), 15)

    #5 XtraSmall Circles
    xsc = [[453,237], [474,325], [400,365], [325,325], [350,237]]

    for i in range (len(xsc)):
        xsc[i] = Circle(Point(xsc[i][0], xsc[i][1]), 8)

    #16 Lines
    l1 = [[532,90], [540,93], [620,180], [622,185], [613,430], [609,435], [520,520], [515,520], [310,457], [305,454], [240,380], [235,378], [178,187], [180,182], [265,90], [270,88]]
    l2 = [[500,150], [505,156], [555,210], [558,215], [555,390], [550,396], [490,454], [485,456], [275,519], [270,516], [180,420], [178,415], [242,216], [244,212], [300,150], [304,150]]
    n = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    for i in range (len(n)):
        n[i] = Line(Point(l1[i][0], l1[i][1]), Point(l2[i][0],l2[i][1]))

    #Star
    p1 = Polygon(Point(400,200), Point(440,260), Point(498,280), Point(450,320), Point(470,370), Point(400,345), Point(327,369), Point(345,320), Point(303,280), Point(360,260))

    #Red Box
    p2 = Polygon(Point(400,480), Point(480,560), Point(400,650), Point(325,560))

    #Triangle
    p3 = Polygon(Point(400,120), Point(437,207), Point(503,153), Point(478,238), Point(556,213), Point(500,280), Point(580,305), Point(495,330), Point(555,395), Point(470,373), Point(488,455), Point(400,400), Point(307,454), Point(328,370), Point(235,378), Point(305,330), Point(220,303), Point(303,280), Point(242,215),Point(330,230), Point(300,150), Point(370,205))

    r1 = Rectangle(Point(650,300),Point(580,305))
    r2 = Rectangle(Point(397,50),Point(404,120))
    r3 = Rectangle(Point(220,300),Point(150,305))

    for i in range(3):
        c[i].draw(win)
        c[i].setWidth(3)

    c[0].setFill('lavender')
    c[1].setFill('orange')
    c[2].setFill('red')

    colors = []  # ADDED
    for i in range(10):
        r = random.randrange(256)
        b = random.randrange(256)
        g = random.randrange(256)
        color = color_rgb(r, g, b)         # ADDED
        colors.append(color)               # ADDED
        mc[i].draw(win)
        mc[i].setWidth(3)
        mc[i].setFill(color)  # CHANGED


    for i in range(11):
        sc[i].draw(win)
        sc[i].setWidth(3)

    for i in range(5):
        xsc[i].draw(win)
        xsc[i].setWidth(3)

    for i in range(16):
        n[i].draw(win)
        n[i].setFill('brown')
        n[i].setWidth(3)


    p1.draw(win)
    p1.setWidth(3)
    p1.setFill('yellow')

    p2.draw(win)
    p2.setFill("red")
    p2.setWidth(3)

    p3.draw(win)
    p3.setWidth(3)
    p3.setOutline('purple')

    r1.draw(win)
    r1.setOutline('brown')
    r1.setWidth(3)

    r2.draw(win)
    r2.setOutline('brown')
    r2.setWidth(3)

    r3.draw(win)
    r3.setOutline('brown')
    r3.setWidth(3)

    message = Text(Point(400,560), '福')
    message.setSize(30)
    message.setFill('gold')
    message.draw(win)

#    win.getMouse()  # MOVED.
#    win.close()     # MOVED.

# ADDED.
def draw_mcs(win):
    """ Redraw the mc circles and change their color to black once in a while. """
    global colors  # ADDED
    global mc      # ADDED

    for i in range(10):
        mc[i].undraw()
        mc[i].draw(win)
        mc[i].setWidth(3)
        color = colors[i] if random.randint(0, RATE) else BLACK
        mc[i].setFill(color)  # CHANGED

# MAIN LOOP.
win = GraphWin('Lantern', 800, 800, autoflush=False)
lantern(win)
for _ in range(100):
    draw_mcs(win)
    update(10)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```